# Can't stop UITableView's scroll movement with another scroll pan if the original movement is too fast

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a `UITableViewController` with custom `UITableViewCell`s. If I scroll relatively slow, the movement can easily be stopped with another small pan or tap. However, if the scrolling is faster, I need to make a much larger movement to reverse the direction of scrolling. Also, stopping it with a tap simply doesn’t work.

I want the default behavior back (like in the Phone app or simply any other application with a long `UITableView`). What can I do in order to have it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my code inside `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` had a negative impact on the performance of my app. I got rid of the code and this issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

```
func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
         return false
}
```

Add Gesturedelegate in your code.